# 3D animated show with a magic wristwatch that spawns lamp posts

Tags: story-identification, animation

I remember watching a 3D animated show of some kind (series, TV special, movie?) in the late 90's or early 2000's.  It *probably* would have aired on Nickelodeon or Cartoon Network, based on my viewing habits at the time.  The Disney Channel is also a possibility, but much less likely.

The setting was probably some kind of cyberspace-esque environment.  The characters were humanoid but had very unusual skin tones (teal?).  A male character had a wristwatch which he could use to attack enemies, [calling his attacks](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Laconic/CallingYourAttacks) (TVTropes link) as "[Trigger word]: [name of attack]."  [Trigger word] might have been "blix" or "blinx," but it's possible I'm confusing it with [this unrelated thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinx:_The_Time_Sweeper).

I remember two scenes in considerable detail.  In the first scene, that male character goes up against a particularly strong enemy (who might have been the main villain).  He uses a large number of attacks on this enemy, one of which involves spawning a lamp post so the enemy can whack his head on it (I think the other attacks were more conventional).  Then his watch runs out of energy, it informs him of this with a sad-face emoticon (and maybe it also beeps?), and he flees.

Later, the same male character is in a long hallway with a female character, when enemies (or missiles?) approach them from both ends of the hall.  He tells her that he can't help, saying "I'm all [trigger word]ed out."  He suggests using the energy in her watch to power his.  She objects, saying "I'll lose all my data" or words to that effect.  They jointly decide that their lives are more valuable than her data, and connect their watches.  Each watch has a [progress bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_bar) that shows how much power it has, and we see hers drain as his fills.  He then spawns a pair of missiles which fly in opposite directions and blow up both of the enemies/missiles just in time.

I think later he found a charging station of some kind, which I think involved him taking the watch off and having it float in some kind of anti-gravity field.  My memory is pretty spotty on this part, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be [Reboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReBoot)?

- It was one of the first 3D animated TV shows and aired in the late 90s on Cartoon Network.
- The setting was the inside of a computer.
- The characters were humanoid, but had blue or green skin.
- The main character had a wristwatch-like gadget called Glitch which could be activated by shouting 'Glitch: Something'.  It had a battery that sometimes needed charging.

Comment: TVTropes [lists the lamp post incident here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Funny/ReBoot), so I'm going to say this is it.

Comment: I specifically remember an episode of ReBoot where the main character (Bob) tells Glitch to turn into "Anything!" and a lamp post was created. Incidentally there is a ReBoot reboot in the works by Netflix; initial trailers show that they completely changed the storyline, feel, and tone of the show, in addition to making it look terrible. Why they decided to call it the same thing is beyond me. Okay, enough of my soap box for now.