Late 90s cartoon where a boy had to fight in a cube as an adult with a golden eye
The town gets invaded by this cube that the boy had to travel to in the air to transform into an adult and go through gauntlets to fight a boss. As an adult, he had a gold eye that he uses to manifest weapons and see things normal eyes can't.

Go through gauntlets? Gauntlets as in various challenges?

I don't have the energy to write up a full answer, but this is Reboot (1994-2001). The character OP is thinking of is Enzo Matrix.

@Ziggy I can't believe I didn't recognise it but you're right!

@Ziggy - Would you like to post a proper answer now that the OP appears to have confirmed that Reboot is the show they were looking for? Or should someone else go ahead and do it?

@Valorum  the op probably means running the gauntlet.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_the_gauntlet

@Ziggy: I hope you don't mind that I went ahead and ran with your comment.

@Al_B You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

As seen in the comments, this is ReBoot, a Canadian animated television series that aired between 1994 and 2001.


The show follows the adventures of a Guardian named Bob and his companions Enzo and Dot Matrix within the computer system world of Mainframe as they work to keep it safe from the viruses known as Megabyte and Hexadecimal, in addition to other threats. Recurring plot threads include the User loading a game into the system, manifesting as an electrical violet cube lowered onto part of the city. Anyone trapped inside become NPCs and have the chance to play against the User. If the User wins, the area is destroyed (a.k.a. nullified) and the residents are reduced to leech-like creatures called Nulls. The setting of the inner world of a computer system, known by its inhabitants as Mainframe, was deliberately chosen due to technological constraints at the time, as the fictional computer world allowed for blocky-looking models and mechanical animation.

The character you are remembering is the aged-up Enzo from Season 3.


Originally Dot's Bratty Half-Pint brother. In the 3rd season, he underwent a Plot-Relevant Age-Up into a super strong badass with a short fuse, a hatred of viruses, and a homicidal hatred of Megabyte in particular. The adult Enzo has a copy of Bob's Guardian code, meaning that he has technically all the immunities a Guardian has to the web and viral infections, although he never had any Guardian training. The lack of training, however, does not make him any less dangerous (Heck, it probably makes him more dangerous). He takes on the name "Matrix" and it sticks when a younger copy of him is created at the end of season 3.


Weirdly enough, the only accepted answer I can find for the series is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178116/3d-animated-show-with-a-magic-wristwatch-that-spawns-lamp-posts/178121#178121 although we have some highly upvoted unaccepted ones.
